# Adding a legend to a ColorFunction Line

Tags: color, legending

I have a plot with a color-varying line, and am looking to make a color-varying LineLegend to accompany it. However, ColorFunction doesn't work for legends it seems, so I'm not sure how to manage this. For example:

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]], PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, {"Line"}]]
```

Results in:
[image: Result]

But I'm looking for the "Line" legend to have a rainbow appearance as well.

Comment: `Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][y]], 
     PlotLegends -> BarLegend["Rainbow"]]` as a start.

Comment: It is a duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201821/using-plotlegends-with-a-colorfunction).